# JOIN column depending on date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. The first (`LOG`) represents a log file with an `ID`, a `timestamp` and arbitrary other columns:

```
  id           timestamp
   1 2016-01-11 15:14:33
   2 2016-01-12 15:14:33
   3 2016-01-13 15:14:33
   4 2016-01-14 15:14:33
   5 2016-01-15 15:14:33
   6 2016-01-16 15:14:33
   7 2016-01-17 15:14:33
   8 2016-01-18 15:14:33
   9 2016-01-19 15:14:33
  10 2016-01-20 15:14:33
```

A second table (`STATUS`) stores a status and the respective date, from which on this status is the 'active' one:

```
       date status
 2016-01-02      A
 2016-01-13      B
 2016-01-18      C
```

Status `A` started at `2016-01-02` and was active until `2016-01-13` and so on.

I want to join these to tables to achieve a table looking like this:

```
  id           timestamp  status
   1 2016-01-11 15:14:33       A
   2 2016-01-12 15:14:33       A
   3 2016-01-13 15:14:33       B
   4 2016-01-14 15:14:33       B
   5 2016-01-15 15:14:33       B
   6 2016-01-16 15:14:33       B
   7 2016-01-17 15:14:33       B
   8 2016-01-18 15:14:33       C
   9 2016-01-19 15:14:33       C
  10 2016-01-20 15:14:33       C
```

How can I achieve this using MySQL?

Comment: What's the first column for?

Comment: @Strawberry just some kind of row number, not actually present in the tables

Comment: Get rid of it. It's not helping.

Comment: @Strawberry Done that.

Comment: Borrowing SqlZim's rextest... http://rextester.com/KAGOV11673

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to get the most recent `status` like so:

```
select t.* , (
    select s.`status` 
    from s 
    where s.`date` < t.`timestamp` 
    order by s.`date` desc 
    limit 1
    ) as `status`
from t;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/KAGOV11673